# Android 4.1+/ContactContract: Lookup group to given contactId (derived from lookup a number)

Tags: android, contactscontract

The following function has a phone number as input parameter (e.g. +436641234567 or +436641234567) and performs two lookups in the Contacts database: first, identify the user belonging to this number (this already works) and then to use the id of the user to **get all groups** this contact is assigned to (and this does not work). Test gives back the correct id (again), however, the group is "null".

```
    public String getNameGroupByNumber(Context context, String number) {
    String name = "?";
    String contactId = "0";
    String group = "0";
    String test = "0";

    // Step 1: LookUp Name to given Number
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    String[] contactProjection = new String[] {BaseColumns._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, contactProjection, null, null, null);

    try {
        if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {
            contactLookup.moveToNext();

            name = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            contactId = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));     
        }
    } finally {         
        if (contactLookup != null) {
            contactLookup.close();
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Name: " +name + " ContactId: " + contactId);    // works as expected

    // Step 2: Lookup group memberships of the contact found in step one
    Uri groupURI = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] groupProjection = new String[]{ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID , ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID};
    Cursor groupLookup = contentResolver.query(groupURI, groupProjection, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID+"="+contactId, null, null);

    try {

        if (groupLookup != null && groupLookup.getCount() > 0) {
            groupLookup.moveToNext();

             test = groupLookup.getString(groupLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID));
             group = groupLookup.getString(groupLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID));

             Log.d(TAG, "Group found with Id: " + test + " and GroupId: " + group);   // test is again the contactID from above but group is null

        }
    } finally {         
        if (groupLookup != null) {
            groupLookup.close();
        }
    }

    return name;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cursor groupLookup = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID , 
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID
        },
        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? AND " + ContactContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
        new String[]{
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                contact_id
        }, null
);
```

Use this `groupLookup` cursor instead.

```
Cursor groupCursor = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{
                ContactsContract.Groups._ID,
                ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE
        }, ContactsContract.Groups._ID + "=" + _id, null, null
);
```

`groupCursor` helps to get Group title from _id.

Comment: Thanks a lot....works out of the box (despite one mission s on ContactSContract). I am a bit confused it returns Group-IDs (e.g. in one example 1, 2, 4) that I do not get when querying the groups with the following code (lowest ID is 3 there):      final String[] GROUP_PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.Groups._ID, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE };
     Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, GROUP_PROJECTION, ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED + "=0", null, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE); Something with Starred in Android or Google Circles? Any idea?

Comment: Forgot to mention: those IDs do not show up, when I query groups marked for deletion.

Comment: I have edited the answer. I used the `groupCursor` to get the group title. But I haven't checked it with groups with `ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED + "=1"` . It works well with getting group title from groups with `ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED + "=0"`.